# How to keep div elements at bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I have a two-columned div element that I need to have at the bottom of the page to act as a footer. The problem is I have tried using `position:fixed` and `bottom:0` to make the element appear at the bottom. This works but only brings one of the `#column` divs down to the bottom, the other disappears. I would appreciate any assistance.

Code:

```css
/* ~ Copyright (c) Macleay Netball Association (made by Tom Carpenter for Year 11 IPT Assessment Task #2.) 2019. */

html>body {
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  /* Trebuchet MS as main font throughout website, sans-serif acting as a backup */
}

#wrapper {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background: #1B315E;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Alignment of DropDown Navigation Menu and Slideshow */
}

.navigation {
  background: #444;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
}

.menuDropDown {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.menuDropDown>#menuButton {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 16px 16px;
  /* Will result in final height of navigation */
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  color: #FFF;
}

#menuButton:hover,
.navigation>.menuDropDown:hover>#menuButton {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #666;
  color: #1B315E;
}

.menuDropDown:hover>.menuContent {
  display: block;
}

.menuContent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  max-height: 85vh;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.menuRow:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}

.menuColumn {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  background: #666;
}

.menuColumn>a {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #1B315E;
}

.menuColumn>a.current {
  background: #777;
}

.menuColumn>a:hover {
  background: #888;
}

.logo {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 43px);
  float: left;
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 8px;
}

.mainHeader {
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}

.mainImg {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.mainBody {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 8px;
}

#column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 8px;
  background: #888;
  bottom: 0;
}

.sponsers {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 8px;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.sponsers:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(80%);
  filter: grayscale(80%);
}

.slideshow {
  /* Slideshow Container containing Images, Sliders and Captions */
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.slides {
  display: none;
}

.slideshowImages {
  width: 100%;
}

.slideButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #888;
  color: #FFF;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mnaHeader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.slideButton:hover {
  background: #666;
}

.previous,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.previous:hover,
.next:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.tableCaption {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #33CC33;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid #888;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}

#headerTable {
  width: 33.33%;
  background: #888;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #33CC33;
}

.linkProp {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.newsPanel {
  width: 100%;
  background: #888;
  height: 135px;
}

.imgNewsPreview {
  width: 215px;
  height: 135px;
  padding: 4px;
  float: left;
}

.newsHeaderPreview {
  color: #FFF;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.newsBodyPreview {
  color: #FFF;
  margin-top: -12px;
}

.caption {
  color: #33CC33;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  bottom: 16px;
}

.collapsible {
  background: #888;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background: #666;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.active:after {
  content: '\2212';
}

.contentCollapsible {
  padding: 0px 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background: #F8F8F8;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  /* To work on Safari (Apple) */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  /* To work on Safari (Apple) */
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.buttonReturn {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #888;
  color: #FFF;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.videoProp {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 400px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /* Stacks navigation menu acting for the site to be responsive */
  .menuColumn {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  /* Stacks Image Header on Top - acting as responsive */
  .column,
  #column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /* Responsive Sponser Images */
  .sponsers {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  /* Increases video resolution as screen reduces */
  .videoProp {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /* Reduces font-size as screen resolution lowers */
  .newsBodyPreview {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  /* Reduces font-sizes within the slideshow <div> */
  .previous,
  .next,
  .caption {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
 ~ Copyright (c) Macleay Netball Association (made by Tom Carpenter for Year 11 IPT Assessment Task #2.) 2019.
-->
<html lang="en-AU">

<head>
  <title>Contact Us &#8212; Macleay Netball Association</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" type="text/css">
  <!-- Internal Stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- External Font Stylesheet -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../Assets/Img/mnaHeader.png">
  <!-- Tab Browser Icon (Favicon) -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="navigation">
      <div class="menuDropDown">
        <button id="menuButton" title="Navigation Menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i> Menu</button>
        <div class="menuContent">
          <div class="menuRow">
            <div class="menuColumn">
              <a title="Home" href="../index.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
              <a title="Association Contacts" href="contacts.html"><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i> Association Contacts</a>
            </div>
            <div class="menuColumn">
              <a title="Weekly Draw" href="weekly-draw.html"><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i> Weekly Draw</a>
              <a title="News" href="#"><i class="far fa-newspaper"></i> News</a>
            </div>
            <div class="menuColumn">
              <a title="Quick Links" href="links.html"><i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i> Quick Links</a>
              <a title="Representative Teams" href="representative-teams.html"><i class="fas fa-certificate"></i> Representative Teams</a>
            </div>
            <div class="menuColumn">
              <a title="Documentation" href="documentation.html"><i class="fas fa-file"></i> Documentation</a>
              <a class="current" title="Contact Us" href="contact-us.html"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i> Contact Us</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="../index.html"><img src="../Assets/Img/mnaHeader.png" alt="Macleay Netball Association" title="Macleay Netball Association" class="logo"></a>
      <!-- Macleay Netball Association Main Logo -->
    </div>
    <!-- End of Navigation -->
    <div class="main">
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3417.0548484369647!2d152.83521681537312!3d-31.080401281517187!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x6b9ddf84d6da904b%3A0xfc941d1ded8f7a25!2sPam+Guyer+Netball+Centre!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sau!4v1559129788713!5m2!1sen!2sau"
        width="100%" height="400px" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <!-- Google Maps Embed -->
      <br>

      <div class="row">
        <div id="column">1</div>
        <div id="column">2</div>
      </div>
      <!-- End of Footer -->
    </div>
    <!-- End of Main -->
  </div>
  <!-- End of Wrapper -->
</body>

</html>
```

Attached are some images if I put `position:fixed` `bottom:0` in the `#column` CSS Code. Only Column 2 goes down, 1 is hidden.

[image]

Comment: You can't use the same id twice.  Change to `class="footer"`, adjust your css accordingly.

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: @bluemoon6790 You can with CSS alone. Only JS does not work with multiple id-attributes having the same value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve this having responsiveness in mind and easier manipulation on different screen sizes is wrapping the two div elements in another div that you will position fixed on the bottom and then adjusting the two divs to take 50% of its parent. You've done half of this job by putting the divs into a `.row` wrapper.

The best solution would probably be using flex to adjust the divs in their parent wrapper like this:

Plus, you can not use the same id twice as it is in your example.

```
<div class="row">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
 </div>

<style>
    .row {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;

        display: flex;
    }
    .row > div {
        flex: 1;
    }
</style>
```

Then on mobile devices you can just change the flex direction and the footer will become one-columned instead of two-columned. Like this:

```
<style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .row {
            flex-direction: column;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: When responsive, the columns won't expand to the whole screen, width:100% won't do it.

Comment: Which browser? They expand well on my end. Try `flex-basis: 100%;` instaed width in the media query.

Comment: chrome, still no luck

Comment: Aah, I know. You are missing the viewport meta tag, and Chrome mobile simulator can not recognize media queries. Add this somewhere in the `<head>` portion of your code: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Can you please send a screenshot of how it looks on mobile when you test it? Once I added the viewport meta tag, it looks good on whichever browser I tried (as it should regarding the code). Maybe you have another leftover @media query css that does something to the same elements to keep them inline.
Here is a fiddle of how I have it setup: https://jsfiddle.net/pesovski/8390z6jb/3/

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the element you want as a footer, remove the class and use the css below to style the element.

```
#footer {
clear: both;
}
```

```
<div id="footer">
<div id="column">1</div>
<div id="column">2</div>
</div> <!-- End of Footer -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `1` and `2` are fixed to the bottom. Only the `float: left` has no effect here and they are at the exactly same position. The `2` is in front of `1` and latter is not visible behind `2`

Do this instead.

```
<div class="row footer">
  <div id="column">1</div>
  <div id="column">2</div>
</div>
```

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```css
/* ~ Copyright (c) Macleay Netball Association (made by Tom Carpenter for Year 11 IPT Assessment Task #2.) 2019. */

html>body {
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  /* Trebuchet MS as main font throughout website, sans-serif acting as a backup */
}

#wrapper {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background: #1B315E;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Alignment of DropDown Navigation Menu and Slideshow */
}

.navigation {
  background: #444;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
}

.menuDropDown {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.menuDropDown>#menuButton {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 16px 16px;
  /* Will result in final height of navigation */
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  color: #FFF;
}

#menuButton:hover,
.navigation>.menuDropDown:hover>#menuButton {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #666;
  color: #1B315E;
}

.menuDropDown:hover>.menuContent {
  display: block;
}

.menuContent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  max-height: 85vh;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.menuRow:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}

.menuColumn {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  background: #666;
}

.menuColumn>a {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #1B315E;
}

.menuColumn>a.current {
  background: #777;
}

.menuColumn>a:hover {
  background: #888;
}

.logo {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 43px);
  float: left;
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 8px;
}

.mainHeader {
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}

.mainImg {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.mainBody {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 8px;
}

#column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 8px;
  background: #888;
  bottom: 0;
}

.sponsers {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 8px;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.sponsers:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(80%);
  filter: grayscale(80%);
}

.slideshow {
  /* Slideshow Container containing Images, Sliders and Captions */
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.slides {
  display: none;
}

.slideshowImages {
  width: 100%;
}

.slideButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #888;
  color: #FFF;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mnaHeader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.slideButton:hover {
  background: #666;
}

.previous,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.previous:hover,
.next:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.tableCaption {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #33CC33;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid #888;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}

#headerTable {
  width: 33.33%;
  background: #888;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #33CC33;
}

.linkProp {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.newsPanel {
  width: 100%;
  background: #888;
  height: 135px;
}

.imgNewsPreview {
  width: 215px;
  height: 135px;
  padding: 4px;
  float: left;
}

.newsHeaderPreview {
  color: #FFF;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.newsBodyPreview {
  color: #FFF;
  margin-top: -12px;
}

.caption {
  color: #33CC33;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  bottom: 16px;
}

.collapsible {
  background: #888;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background: #666;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.active:after {
  content: '\2212';
}

.contentCollapsible {
  padding: 0px 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background: #F8F8F8;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  /* To work on Safari (Apple) */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  /* To work on Safari (Apple) */
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.buttonReturn {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #888;
  color: #FFF;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.videoProp {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 400px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /* Stacks navigation menu acting for the site to be responsive */
  .menuColumn {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  /* Stacks Image Header on Top - acting as responsive */
  .column,
  #column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /* Responsive Sponser Images */
  .sponsers {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  /* Increases video resolution as screen reduces */
  .videoProp {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /* Reduces font-size as screen resolution lowers */
  .newsBodyPreview {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  /* Reduces font-sizes within the slideshow <div> */
  .previous,
  .next,
  .caption {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="navigation">
    <div class="menuDropDown">
      <button id="menuButton" title="Navigation Menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i> Menu</button>
      <div class="menuContent">
        <div class="menuRow">
          <div class="menuColumn">
            <a title="Home" href="../index.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
            <a title="Association Contacts" href="contacts.html"><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i> Association Contacts</a>
          </div>
          <div class="menuColumn">
            <a title="Weekly Draw" href="weekly-draw.html"><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i> Weekly Draw</a>
            <a title="News" href="#"><i class="far fa-newspaper"></i> News</a>
          </div>
          <div class="menuColumn">
            <a title="Quick Links" href="links.html"><i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i> Quick Links</a>
            <a title="Representative Teams" href="representative-teams.html"><i class="fas fa-certificate"></i> Representative Teams</a>
          </div>
          <div class="menuColumn">
            <a title="Documentation" href="documentation.html"><i class="fas fa-file"></i> Documentation</a>
            <a class="current" title="Contact Us" href="contact-us.html"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i> Contact Us</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="../index.html"><img src="../Assets/Img/mnaHeader.png" alt="Macleay Netball Association" title="Macleay Netball Association" class="logo"></a>
    <!-- Macleay Netball Association Main Logo -->
  </div>
  <!-- End of Navigation -->
  <div class="main">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3417.0548484369647!2d152.83521681537312!3d-31.080401281517187!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x6b9ddf84d6da904b%3A0xfc941d1ded8f7a25!2sPam+Guyer+Netball+Centre!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sau!4v1559129788713!5m2!1sen!2sau"
      width="100%" height="400px" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <!-- Google Maps Embed -->
    <br>

    <div class="row footer">
      <div id="column">1</div>
      <div id="column">2</div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Footer -->
  </div>
  <!-- End of Main -->
</div>
<!-- End of Wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `id` must be unique for an element, shouldn't set same id on two elements.

When you set position `fixed` on an element it is positioned relative to viewport, not relative to flow of the page.

Both of your elements have `bottom: 0`, which is relative to browser window, that's why your first element is covered by the second one (it's not hidden). You can group them in the same parent and position the parent, so your elements are stacked as expected. Take a look at the following code:

```css
body {
    min-height: 200vh;
}

#column {
    display: block;
    padding 15px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #e5e5e5;
}

#column div {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #9b009b;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="column">
    <div>first col</div>
    <div>second col</div>
</div>
```